# Python 2.7.7 Breaking?

Tags: python, if-statement, raw-input

I am trying to make a memory game in python 2.7.7 i need some help with My Code.

```
Guess1_Easy_Removed = raw_input("Which Word Do You Think Was Removed?:")
if Guess1_Easy_Removed == wordList[9]:
    print "Correct!"
else:
    print "Try Again!"
Guess2_Easy_Removed = raw_input("Which Word Do You Think Was Removed?:")
if Guess2_Easy_Removed == wordList[9]:
    print "Correct!"
else:
    print "Try Again!"
Guess3_Easy_Removed = raw_input("Which Word Do You Think Was Removed?:")
if Guess3_Easy_Removed == wordList[9]:
    print "Correct!"
else:
    print "Try Again!"

Guess1_Easy_Substitute= raw_input("Which Word Do You Think Was The Substitute Word?:")
if Guess1_Easy_Substitute == wordList[5]:
    print "Correct!"    
else:
    print "Try Again!"

Guess2_Easy_Substitute= raw_input("Which Word Do You Think Was The Substitute Word?:")
if Guess2_Easy_Substitute == wordList[5]:
    print "Correct!"
else:
    print "Try Again!"
Guess3_Easy_Substitute= raw_input("Which Word Do You Think Was The Substitute Word?:")
if Guess3_Easy_Substitute == wordList[5]:
    print "Correct!"
else:
    print "Try Again!"
```

The things i need help with are :
if the user guesses the removed or substitute word right all other guesses should be stopped. if Removed & substitute words guessed correctly i need to , print "You win" do i need to use the break statement? Thanks

Comment: Does this run inside a loop?

Comment: No, do you think i should set one up so i can use break??

Comment: No need, please check answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
Guess1_Easy_Substitute= raw_input("Which Word Do You Think Was The Substitute Word?:")
while Guess1_Easy_Substitute != wordList[5]:
    Guess1_Easy_Substitute= raw_input("Try again! Which Word Do You Think Was The Substitute Word?:")
    if Guess1_Easy_Substitute == wordList[5]:
        print "You win"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping the indentation issues in your code is just a copy/paste mistake, otherwise the program would not be running at all. If your code runs inside a loop (like a `for` loop or `while` loop) , then you can use `break` statement to exit out of the loop.

Example of loop -

```
while True:
    Guess1_Easy_Removed = raw_input("Which Word Do You Think Was Removed?:")
    if Guess1_Easy_Removed == wordList[9]:
        print "Correct!"
        break    # <------- This would transfer the control out of the loop.
    else:
        print "Try Again!"
    ...... # you will need to do the break for all such scenarios.
```

---

If you are not using loops, and then you can use `sys.exit(0)` ( 0 indicates a successful run of the program) , for this you would need to import the `sys` module to the program , before using `sys.exit()` . This would cause the program to end.

Example -

```
import sys
Guess1_Easy_Removed = raw_input("Which Word Do You Think Was Removed?:")
if Guess1_Easy_Removed == wordList[9]:
    print "Correct!"
    sys.exit(0)    # <------- This would cause the program to end.
else:
    print "Try Again!"
...... # you will need to do the break for all such scenarios.
```

Comment: Thanks, the indentation was a copy paste mistake and this is only part of a program much bigger, Thanks again